How do I correctly generate applications in production with Tauri v2 Rust for Android?
I'm programming an android app using Tauri v2 in Rust. When I do "bun run tauri android dev" the app runs perfectly on my mobile but when I pass it to production "bun run tauri android build" it generates the apk, "app-universal-release-unsigned.apk" but when I try to install it on the mobile I get an error saying: "package info is null" and it does not let you install it. Does anyone have any idea what it could be?
I attach a chunk of my code of "lib.rs" and my "tauri.conf.json" files:
{
  "productName": "beta",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "identifier": "com.tauri.build",
  "build": {
    "beforeDevCommand": "bun run dev",
    "devUrl": "http://localhost:1420",
    "beforeBuildCommand": "bun run build",
    "frontendDist": "../dist"
  },
  
  "app": {"windows": [
      {
        "title": "beta",
        "width": 800,
        "height": 600
      }
    ],
    "security": {
      "assetProtocol": {
        "enable": false,
        "scope": []
      },
      "dangerousDisableAssetCspModification": false,
      "freezePrototype": false,
      "pattern": {
        "use": "brownfield"
      }
    }
  },
  "bundle": {
    "active": false,
    "targets": "all",
    "icon": [
      "icons/32x32.png",
      "icons/128x128.png",
      "icons/128x128@2x.png",
      "icons/icon.icns",
      "icons/icon.ico"
    ],
    "android": {
      "minSdkVersion": 24
    },
    "category": "Sports",
    "shortDescription": "A simple app to test the beta version of Tauri"
  
  }
}

#[cfg_attr(mobile, tauri::mobile_entry_point)]
pub fn run() {
    let package_info = PackageInfo {
        name: "beta".to_string(),
        version: Version::new(2, 1, 1),
        authors: "author",
        description: "description",
        crate_name: "beta",
    };

    let mut context = tauri::generate_context!();
    let info = context.package_info_mut();
    info.name = package_info.name;
    info.authors = package_info.authors;   
    info.description = package_info.description;
    info.version = package_info.version;
    info.crate_name = package_info.crate_name;

    tauri::Builder::default()
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_shell::init())
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![start, stop, greet, print_files, manually])
        .run(context)
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

Is there some line of code that I'm missing to build an apk using tauri rust for production?

You should be able to build Tauri (beta 2.x) app for Android in release mode using:
npm tauri android build

For the keys configuration, I know there were some changes in the recent beta, but the most recent docs are here. It's probably a subject to change for the future releases. Same as API changed from alpha to beta.

Hey, thank you first of all for trying to answer the question, I don't have any problem with generating the apk, my problem is that when Rust generates it on any device I try to install-it I get the message "package info is null". In the documentation that you have sent me it details how to sign the application to upload it to the play store, but is it a mandatory requirement if it is not uploaded to the play store at the moment? I should still be able to install the APK, right?

Why do you need to generate the context dynamically and not via tauri.conf file?
